# Why may thread_local not be applied to non-static data members and how to implement thread-local non-static data members?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, openmp, thread-local-storage

Why may `thread_local` not be applied to non-static data members? The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999131/can-you-use-thread-local-variables-inside-a-class-or-structure) says: "There is no point in making non-static structure or class members thread-local." Honestly, I see many good reasons to make non-static data members thread-local.

Assume we have some kind of `ComputeEngine` with a member function `computeSomething` that is called many times in succession. Some of the work inside the member function can be done in parallel. To do so, each thread needs some kind of `ComputeHelper` that provides, for example, auxiliary data structures. So what we actually want is the following:

```
class ComputeEngine {
 public:
  int computeSomething(Args args) {
    int sum = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
      // ...
      helper.xxx();
      // ...
    }
    return sum;
  }
 private:
  thread_local ComputeHelper helper;
};
```

Unfortunately, this code will not compile. What we could do instead is this:

```
class ComputeEngine {
 public:
  int computeSomething(Args args) {
    int sum = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
      ComputeHelper helper;
      #pragma omp for reduction(+:sum)
      for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        // ...
        helper.xxx();
        // ...
      }
    }
    return sum;
  }
};
```

However, this will construct and destruct the `ComputeHelper` between successive calls of `computeSomething`. Assuming that constructing the `ComputeHelper` is expensive (for example, due to the allocation und initialization of huge vectors), we may want to reuse the `ComputeHelper`s between successive calls. This leads me to the following boilerplate approach:

```
class ComputeEngine {
  struct ThreadLocalStorage {
    ComputeHelper helper;
  };
 public:
  int computeSomething(Args args) {
    int sum = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
      ComputeHelper &helper = tls[omp_get_thread_num()].helper;
      #pragma omp for reduction(+:sum)
      for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        // ...
        helper.xxx();
        // ...
      }
    }
    return sum;
  }
 private:
  std::vector<ThreadLocalStorage> tls;
};
```

1. Why may `thread_local` not be applied to non-static data members? What
   is the rationale behind this restriction? Have I not given a good
   example where thread-local non-static data members make perfect
   sense?
2. What are best practices to implement thread-local non-static
   data members?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for why `thread_local` cannot be applied to non-static data members, it would disrupt the usual ordering guarantee of such members.  That is, data members within a single `public/private/protected` group must be laid out in memory in the same order as in the class declaration.  Not to mention what happens if you allocate a class on the stack--the TLS members would not go on the stack.

As for how to work around this, I suggest using [`boost::thread_specific_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html).  You can put one of these inside your class and get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 2):

The way that thread local storage usually works is that you get exactly one pointer in a thread specific data structure (e.g. [TEB in Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686708(v=vs.85).aspx)

As long as all thread local variables are static, the compiler can easily compute the size of these fields, allocate a struct of the size and assign a static offset into that struct to each field.

As soon as you allow non static fields this whole scheme becomes way more complicated - one way to solve it would be one additional level of indirection and storing an index in each class (now you have hidden fields in classes, rather unexpected).

Instead of hoisting the complexity of such a scheme on the implementer, they apparently decided to let each application deal with it on a need basis.