# C++ Member variable copied for each thread (thread_local-like)

Tags: c++, multithreading, global-variables, thread-local

I have an object that during initialization creates several [shared memories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx).
The different properties of each shared memory (`HANDLE`, name, buffer pointer, etc...) are stored in a struct I made and pushed in a `vector<SharedMemory>`.
Once this is done, it creates as many threads on a function `MyClass::Server(unsigned int sharedMemoryID)` as it created shared memories. `sharedMemoryID` being the ID of the shared memory in the `vector`, this way `Server()` knows which shared memory to use.
It then gets ready to serve requests (I use the shared memory as an [Inter Process Communication system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx)).
This way, each thread uses its own private shared memory and I can treat multiple requests in parallel.
I keep the `thread` stored in a member variable of my class `map<unsigned int, thread> m_servers`.
I also have a function to send requests and responses in the shared memory named `MyClass::Send(unsigned int sharedMemoryID, const void* source, unsigned int length)`

What I would like is to avoid having to pass the `sharedMemoryID` at every functions called after `Server()` since all of the functions related to send and receive can only be called after `Server()` this is redundant.
To do so I would like to have a member variable `unsigned int m_serverID` that would have its own copy in each thread and that would be written straightaway when `Server()` gets executed. This way all other functions called afterwards could avoid having `sharedMemoryID` as argument and jsut get the ID to use from this member variable thread-specific.

I tried to add in my class `thread_local unsigned int m_serverID;` but it says that *thread-local storage class is not valid here*. One thing that works is to declare **outside my class** `static thread_local unsigned int serverID;` then changing it from my thread, but I would like to have this variable in my object, not being global.

I searched on StackOverflow and on Google and many people seemed to say that what I am looking for make no sense and I have to admit that I don't quite understand why.

**Could you tell me if there is a way to have member variables thread-local and if not, could you suggest alternatives and tell me precisely why this is not possible please?**

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999131/can-you-use-thread-local-variables-inside-a-class-or-structure?rq=1  see if this helps at all...

Comment: A namespace variable, a local static , and a class static member can be declared thread_local . (Stroustrup) - so yes you can make this variable a member - just make it static member

Comment: Thank you @ttemple That did help. If I understand well, when I call the thread on my function, my thread works with a copy of the object, so modifying a normal member variable will only modify it for this thread? However, in my thread, I pass the object by reference this way: `m_servers[smNewID] = thread(&MyClass::Server, ref(*this), smNewID);` Since it is passed by reference, I suppose this means that all threads use the same object and it is not copied right?